# Related to projection principles in a linear vector field with complex scalar product definition

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

In a linear vector space $\mathcal{S}$ where vectors (denoted $x, y, z, \cdots$) can be complex-valued and for a complex field of multiplier parameters (denoted $\alpha, \beta, \cdots$), we assume that a scalar product is defined with the following properties

$$ \langle x,y \rangle=\langle y,x\rangle^{*} $$
$$ \langle \alpha_{1}x_{1}+\alpha_{2}x_{2},y \rangle = \alpha_{1}^{*} \langle x_{1},y \rangle +\alpha_{2}^{*} \langle x_{2},y \rangle $$
$$ \langle x,x \rangle >0 \ \ \ \textrm{if: } \ x\neq0, $$
where $^{*}$ denotes complex conjugation.

The question here is to find the value of $\alpha$ that will minimize $|x-\alpha y|$ and then show that such value will make the vectors $y$ and $x-\alpha y$ orthogonal. This is an instructive question (from [Friedman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486664449), p. 8) to introduce projection theory, but starting from the basic principles and definitions given above only.

I can prove this when the definition is for real vectors, real scalar product and real parameters, by making the length $|x-\alpha y|$ vanish, leading to a quadratic equation in $\alpha$ as

$$ \alpha^{2}-2\alpha \frac{\langle x,y \rangle}{|y|^{2}}+\frac{|x|^{2}}{|y|^{2}}=0, $$

which can be solved for a real value of $\alpha$ taking into account the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $|\langle x,y\rangle|\leq |x|^{2}|y|^{2}$, to get the sought value: $\alpha_{min}=\langle x,y \rangle/|y|^{2}$, and the rest of the question is then easy to answer.

However, I am having difficulty proving it for the case of complex scalar product definition and complex parameters given above.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you have in the complex case?

Comment: @MaoWao The complex conjugates $\alpha \langle x,y\rangle$ and $\alpha^{*}\langle x,y\rangle^{*}$ appear in the equation and it does not reduce to a normal quadratic equation form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding the inner product, one gets (with $a=\mathrm{Re}\alpha$, $b=\mathrm{Im}\alpha$):
\begin{align*}
|x-\alpha y|^2&=|x|^2-2\mathrm{Re}(\alpha\langle x,y\rangle)+|\alpha|^2|y|^2\\
&=|x|^2-2a\mathrm{Re}\langle x,y\rangle+2b\mathrm{Im}\langle x,y\rangle+(a^2+b^2)|y|^2.
\end{align*}
For $\alpha$ to minimize this expression, the partial derivatives with respect to $a$ and $b$ need to vanish:
\begin{align*}
0&=\frac\partial{\partial a}|x-\alpha y|^2=-2\mathrm{Re}\langle x,y\rangle+2a|y|^2,\\
0&=\frac\partial{\partial b}|x-\alpha y|^2=2\mathrm{Im}\langle x,y\rangle+2b|y|^2.
\end{align*}
Thus $a=\mathrm{Re}\langle x,y\rangle/|y|^2$ and $b=-\mathrm{Im}\langle x,y\rangle/|y|^2$, that is, $\alpha=\langle y,x\rangle/|y|^2$.

I'll leave it to you to show that $\alpha$ is actually a minimizer and the orthogonality relation is satisfied.

Comment: Ah, yes! I can see where I erred now. Many thanks!